# Write scope within dynamic string

Tags: angularjs

I am working on localization within my angular project. It reads a JSON file which is having key and it's localized value in string.

Like: `text1:"Localized text"`

This prints "Localized text" on page correctly. But when I need to add some dynamic text in the string, like:

`text1: "Showing page {{cur_page_num}} of {{total_pages}} pages"`

where the `cur_page_num` and `total_pages` values will come from controller. I have tried

`"Showing page {{cur_page_num}} of {{total_pages}} pages"`

but it's printing `{{cur_page_num}}` and `{{total_pages}}` as it is without evaluating it.

Comment: Is it about AngularJS (1.x), or Angular (2+). In any case, why are you reinventing this wheel instead of using what already exists?

Comment: Using Angular1.5

Comment: Use angular-translate: https://angular-translate.github.io/. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

use **ng-bind-html**

EX:

```
<p ng-bind-html="obj.text1"></p>
```

At this point you may get an error.

> attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context error

you need to either use `ngSanitize` or `$sce` to resolve that.

Comment: The string is written in JSON so I can not use text1: "Showing page " + {{cur_page_num}}

Comment: @Gaurav this might be your solution.

Answer (score 1):

try storing the json values in an array .
iterate it on html & render it there .

Answer (score 0):

if it is from template then your code should be like this,

> text1: "Showing page " + {{cur_page_num}} + " of " + {{total_pages}} + " pages"

or if it is from controller then it can be like below,

> text1: "Showing page " + $scope.cur_page_num + " of " + $scope.total_pages + " pages"

Comment: It is from JSON file.

Comment: can you share sample json?